# 50 watt high-power LED current problem

Tags: voltage, led, current, led-driver, current-limiting

I am using this 50 watt high power LED:

[image: 50 W high power led].

And want to power it using this voltage booster:

[image: 12v to 34v step up voltage booster]

From 12 V to 34 V as the requirements of the LED datasheet.

- Will it work?

I read that I need to limit the current because the current will burn it.

- Doesn't the LED take just what current it needs from the power supply? How can the current burn it?

Comment: Hi! Your question "doesn't the LED just take the current it needs" demonstrates a lack of basic understanding of electronics! So, please, do your basic research of how LEDs' work.

Comment: In the future, you need to add part numbers to your question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller To be fair, resistive loads do this, so I would say OP may not understand non-linearity of LEDs, rather than electronics broadly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the LED current (and temperature) below its rated values for it to survive.

That voltage booster appears to only have 1 pot, so it likely works in constant voltage mode only. Some can work in constant current mode.

The LED current will increase with voltage very steeply, but you CAN control the current by adjusting the voltage while monitoring the current with a multimeter.

The downside to doing this is that the current will vary considerably as the LED temperature changes.

It's fairly common for boost converters like this to have a constant current mode (it will have 2 adjustment pots). Using that mode is preferable for driving a LED.